# Unbounded subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $x,y \in A \implies \exists z \in A$ such that $x,y,z$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

Let $A  \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ be an unbounded set such that, for each (every) pair of distinct points $x,y \in A, \exists z \in A$ such that $x,y,z$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle. I am trying to classify the types of set $A$ can be, and have discovered the following. $A$ could be:

- Any infinite [hexagonal lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_lattice) of points.
- $\mathbb{R^2}$
- $\mathbb{R^2}$ with any one point removed.
- <s>$\mathbb{R^2}$ with the vertices of any equilateral triangle triangle (3 points) removed.</s> [Notice that $\mathbb{R^2}$ with any two points removed doesn't work. I also suspect: removing 3 or more finite points from $\mathbb{R^2}$ doesn't work].
- <s>$\mathbb{R^2}$ with any infinite hexagonal lattice of points removed.</s>
- Any infinite hexagonal lattice of points with any one point removed from the lattice.
- Any infinite hexagonal lattice of points with two or more points removed from the lattice that "works". [I think I can classify what doesn't work: If you can form two equilateral triangles using two remaining lattice points; one equilateral triangle uses a removed point as the 3rd vertex, and the other equilateral triangle uses another removed point as the 3rd vertex. Everything else should work. ]
- <s>$\mathbb{R^2}$ with any infinite hexagonal lattice of points removed, bar any one point.</s>
- <s>$\mathbb{R^2}$ with any infinite hexagonal lattice of points removed bar any two or more points that "works".[It might require more thought to classify what works here and what doesn't.]</s>
- $\mathbb{R^2}$ with a disc removed, $\mathbb{R^2}$ with a square and it's interior removed,but *not* $\mathbb{R^2}$ with any convex subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ (and its interior) removed (e.g. some ellipses), and also *not* $\mathbb{R^2}$ with any rectangle (and its interior) removed e.g. a 3 unit x 1 unit rectangle.
- ??

I'm  <s>probably</s>  definitely missing some sets.

Feel free to edit the format of this list so that it is laid out clearer.

---

This is an extension to the proposition that Dejan Govc proposed and proved in the link:

[Is there such a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140906/is-there-such-a-function)

Dejan Govc gave a nice answer to the same question for bounded sets (as opposed to unbounded sets- which is what this question is about).